# Return column names where they meet a specific value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a User Table which has "Access Role" Defined in the table itself.

Schema:

```
UserID, UserName, Access_1, Access_2, Access_3, .... Access_10
```

Here values for Access_Columns is 1 or 0

Objective: I need Users and their Allowed accesses in one column as 'Access_Allowed'.

```
UserId, Access_Allowed  
1,     (Access_1, Access_3, Access_4, ...)  
2,     (Access_2, Access_3, Access_5, Access_10, ...)
```

Regards,
Yugal

Comment: 1. See normalization.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Strawberry, I know normalization is required here, But I'm stuck with this schema only (I'm not the designer for sure), needed query for reporting purpose.

Comment: There's absolutely no obligation on your part or the part of your organisation to use a relational database management system. However, if you *are* going to go down that route, then it's helpful to provide relational data. Have a word with the deisgner. In the interim, see CONCAT()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thanks Strawberry... I've Used Concat_ws here...  

select userid, username,  
concat_ws(', ',  
IF(Access1 = 1 ,'Access1', NULL),  
IF(Access2 = 1 ,'Access2', NULL),  
IF(Access3 = 1 ,'Access3', NULL),  
IF(Access4 = 1 ,'Access4', NULL),  
.  
.  
IF( AccessN = 1 ,'AccessN',NULL) as Access_Allowed  
from UserTable

Thanks
```